# No output from MacBook Pro audio jack (input OK)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2009) and I've tried just about everything I can think of to fix this.  The problem is that I can't hear anything out of my headphone jack.  I can set it to input instead of output and I can input audio just fine, but it refuses to output (yes, I'm using the proper "Use audio port for:" settings.)  I can get normal output from the mac speakers.

I can't remember having this problem before.  The only difference is that I just moved into my college dorm.  There was nothing abnormal about the move; put my laptop in its case, headed about 10 miles from my house, and I was there.  Here's what I've tried:

- Resetting the PRAM
- Everything in System Pref>Sound
- Changing bit rate in Audio MIDI Setup
- Jiggling a toothpick into the audio port (No, I don't have the red light problem)
- Taking out, putting to sleep, plugging in, and waking up
- Trying my headphones with something else
- Sacrificing a new-born child

And still nothing works.  Any other suggestions that I haven't thought of would be appreciated!

Comment: You say you've moved dormitories.  What kind of move was that?  From another dorm, across town, or further?  How was the computer transported?  Can you get a qualified tech to look inside the computer?

Comment: Sorry to hear about the baby. :-)

Comment: assume you can get sound out of the Macbook speakers? If not may be an amp issue = motherboard

Comment: Thanks, I will try to get a tech guy to look at, info was updated otherwise.

Comment: Boot from an external system, that will help you figure out wether it's a software or hardware issue.